# How to remove an association on the fly in CakePHP v3

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

In previous versions of CakePHP you could temporarily alter associations with `Table::bindModel('SomeModel');` but I can't figure out how to do it in v3.

I want to temporarily disable a hasMany association that's defined in the Table class because it's causing errors when I run older migrations that were written before that table existed. I don't fully understand the migration problem but it immediately goes away when I comment out the association in the Table class.

```
class AgenciesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('agencies');
        $this->displayField('full_name');
        $this->primaryKey('id');
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->hasMany('Routes');
```

[image]

Comment: It's just a guess but I think it's not implemented in cake3. The reason could be that cake does not actually invoke the relationship until you 'contain' the table in a find() call. So if there is no find() call that contain Routes ake won't check for the existence of that table.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you should *not* rely on the actual model classes when using migrations. This can cause exactly the kind of issue you just encountered.

Instead use the TableRegistry or a Table object directly and create a table object without any dependencies. Load the associations you need directly on that object.

```
$agencies = new Table(['table' => 'agencies', /*...*/]);
$agencies->belongsTo('Whatever');
/* Do your data manipulation */
```

This way the migration will work no matter what other changes has been made to your AgenciesTable class. And this is IMHO the proper way of doing it in migrations.

I think that even if you don't create the association explicit by calling `$this->hasMany('Routes');` you'll end up with the same error because the eager loader will still try to find a matching table class and load it dynamically. This is also the reason why there is no "uncontain" method.

Also you're not showing your actual query code... So I *assume* you're calling a custom find or method that calls Query::contain() somewhere. Just write a new query without that contain?

```
$agencies->find()->contain(['One', 'Two'])->where([/*...*/])->all();
```

If you have a big query it might be a good idea to break it up into more custom finds because they can be combined:

```
$agencies->find('withoutMyContain')->all();
$agencies->find('withoutMyContain')->find('withMyContain')->all();
```

See [Custom Finder Methods](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-finder-methods).

Comment: Thanks! We're getting the error simply from the boilerplate code that you get when you bake a migration. No additional fanciness. I think your workaround is going to work. But I'm wondering if the original problem is a bug. Seems like a very common situation to create a migration then sometime later down the road introduce a new association... That alone shouldn't break the earlier migration right?